# attach source code and debug on Eclipse or IDEA

Tags: java

Our company develop a program, package it as a jar file and deploy it on Nexus.
A web program cite it through Maven.
I download the jar's source code, want to debug and modify it.
How can I attach the source code and debug it on Eclipse or IDEA?

Comment: IDEA: File>Project structure>Libraries - select a library, click plus on the right and select a source jar to attach.

Comment: but I cann't modify the code in jar. I need to modify the code and I have downloaded the code, not the source.jar.

Comment: Your post says 'I download the jar's source code', this means you have the source. If you downloaded the binary jar, then of course you can't modify it.